# ng-if with multiple conditions inside ng-repeat not working as expected

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ng-if

I'm having trouble with something that is supposed to work unless I'm mistaken.

I've got a key:value object set up like this:

```
{
  key1:"val1",
  key2:"val2",
  key3:"val3",
  key4:null
}
```

In my view I have this:

```
<div class="col-md-4" ng-repeat="(key, value) in list" ng-if="key != 'key1' || value != null">
            <ul>
                <li>{{ key }} : {{ value }} </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

The problem:
If I only use `key != 'key1'` works,, the key and value of key1 is not displayed.

If I only use `value != null` works as well,, key4 is not displayed.

But when I combine the if statement with || (OR), the entire if statement is ignored.

Am I doing something wrong here?

I've posted an example over here: http://jsfiddle.net/caxoyud2/

Thanx in advance!

Comment: I am not going to post an answer for this, all you have to do is replace || with && , think about it, you want both conditions to be fullfilled not one of them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want both to disappear it should be '&&' instead of '||'. !(key == 'key1' || value == null), when negation is taken inside '||' becomes '&&'.

```
<div class="col-md-4" ng-repeat="(key, value) in list" ng-if="key != 'key1' &&     value != null">
        <ul>
            <li>{{ key }} : {{ value }} </li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

OR

```
<div class="col-md-4" ng-repeat="(key, value) in list" ng-if="!(key == 'key1' || value == null)">
    <ul>
        <li>{{ key }} : {{ value }}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. And @sylwester, thank you for the explanation: (true || false) = true, forgot about that!

Comment: Thank you. And @sylwester , you saved my day. I was writing it in this way and it did not work. 

`ng-if="key != 'key1'  ||    key == null"`

Maybe someting to do with the way angular parses the condition

Answer (score 0):

Please see demo below

Everything is fine just statement

```
(true || false) = true
```

```js
var someModule = angular.module('myModule', []);

someModule.controller('someControler', function($scope) {

  $scope.list = {
    key1: "val1",
    key2: "val2",
    key3: "val3",
    key4: null
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myModule">
  <div ng-controller="someControler">
    <div class="col-md-4" ng-repeat="(key, value) in list" ng-if="!(key != 'key1' && value != null)">
      <ul>
        <li>{{ key }} : {{ value }}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```